# Groovy optional parentheses and dots

Tags: groovy, dsl

I am learning Groovy and am pretty impressed with how it allows one to build a intelligent DSL, but I am a bit confused by the rules for when parentheses and dots are optional.  Consider the following code:

```
Integer take(Integer x) {x}
take 3 plus 4
```

This works as expected and produces an output of 7 (when ran in the console), as groovy understands that last line as `take(3).plus(4)`.

Now, `println take 3 plus 4` does not work as groovy understands that as `println(take).3(plus).4` which is nonsense.

Every example that I am seeing shows these sort of expression by themselves on a line, but apparently

```
s = take 3 plus 4
```

works and stores the result 7 in s.  My question is, why does

```
println( take 3 plus 4 )
```

not work?  Obviously, groovy will parse these sort of expressions even if they are not by themselves on a line (as shown by the assignment working).  I would have thought that adding those parentheses would remove the ambiguity from the form of that line that doesn't work and that it would print out 7 as I intended.

Instead groovy gives an error 'unexpected token: 3'.  As far as I can tell, groovy will not allow optional parentheses or dots inside that println, even though it doesn't seem to be ambiguous.  When exactly does this sort of trick work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This falls into the category of a nested method call, and in that case you cannot omit the parentheses. This is causing ambiguity and the results are unexpected, as the println method thinks you are passing it multiple parameters.  You could reduce the ambiguity by using a groovy string in the println method.

```
println "${take 3 plus 4}"
```

More info: [Omit Parentheses](http://www.groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_omitting_parentheses)

Comment: That would address why `println take 3 plus 4` doesn't work, but not why `println (take 3 plus 4)` doesn't as there shouldn't be any ambiguity there (if it was to be interpreted as multiple parameters, there would be a comma between them so groovy should be able to determine that is not what was meant).  Additionally that link says that it shouldn't work in assignment either (although the code example shows it working), but it does.  I wonder if that is slightly out of date now.  The language guide isn't quite so strict and suggests that it should work when wrapped like that last form.

Comment: +1 for showing me how I can get that to work in a println, but I'm not sure if this fully answers my question.

Comment: This is ambiguous because the println method doesn't know to evaluate the code  **take 3 plus 4**  _to_  **take(3).plus(4)** prior to performing its operation on it.   Everything to the right of an '=' sign is an expression and is evaluated prior to being assigned to the variable.  The ${} are saying evaluate this code first, then call println on it.

Comment: I'd add this is a parser limitation. Maybe with [antlr4](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-5299)

Comment: @WillP Thank you for that comment, it confirms what I suspected (or at least confirms other people suspect the same thing).  There are a few places where the language spec suggests that this should work but it doesn't.  If the language spec represents the "ideal" implementation, I suspect that it may just be the case that the implementation can't quite accomplish all of it yet.  I've see a few tutorials on the web and the book I'm learning from say things along the lines of "this is a limitation of the current version, and hopefully will be removed in a later version".

Comment: "the println method doesn't know to evaluate" - say what? lol. No I believe this is basically a limitation of Groovy, one way or the other. Another thing I found is that `println` (or any other "nested function call") need not be involved. Try to write this and the compilation fails: `(take 3 plus 4)`.

Comment: @Matthew Interesting conversation. This issue is still not fixed in 2.4.10. Moreover, there seems to be a more fundamental limitation: nothing to do with optional dots either; just optional (or not in this case) parentheses. `take 3` returns 3. `(take 3)` does not compile. You have to write `(take(3))` instead.